# breaking recursion in merge sort algorithm

Tags: python

Recursion isn't breaking when a list of [] is passed to mergesort_helper(). I've tried adding cases to check for None and len < 0 and have inspected the debugger closely. Any suggestions?

```
def mergesort(lyst):
    """Mergesort Algorithm"""
    def mergesort_helper(lower, upper):
        RecursionCounter()
        merged_lyst = []
        while len(lower) > 0 and len(upper) > 0:
            if lower[0] < upper[0]:
                merged_lyst.append(lower[0])
                lower.pop(0)
            else:
                merged_lyst.append(upper[0])
                upper.pop(0)

        while (len(lower)) > 0:
            merged_lyst.append(lower[0])
            lower.pop(0)

        while (len(upper)) > 0:
            merged_lyst.append(upper[0])
            upper.pop(0)

        return merged_lyst

    validate_list(lyst)
    if len(lyst) == 1:
        return lyst
    mid_index = len(lyst) // 2
    if len(lyst) is not None:
        lower = mergesort(lyst[0:mid_index])
        upper = mergesort(lyst[(mid_index + 1):])
        return mergesort_helper(lower, upper)
    return
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code is missing a main program and at least two support functions; it doesn't run as given.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of your implementation flow is here:

```
if len(lyst) is not None:
```

This will *always* take you into the branch to execute.  `len` returns an `int`; the value can *never* be `None`.  This is the source of your infinite recursion.

You have confused the concepts of `None`, `0`, and an empty list.  Although each of them will evaluate to `False` if you coerce them to Boolean, they are *not* equal.  Clean up your call-return sequence: decide what *one* type you will return from each function, and stick to it.  Make your calling function work with *only* that return value.  Insert useful `print` commands to trace the values: this simple technique would have shown the failing `if` in much less time than it takes to post a Stack Overflow question.  For instance:

```
print("mid_index=", mid_index)
print("lyst     =", lyst)
if len(lyst) is not None:
    print("Here I go again!")
    lower = mergesort(lyst[0:mid_index])
    upper = mergesort(lyst[(mid_index + 1):])
    print("Divided into two pieces:", lower, upper)
    return mergesort_helper(lower, upper)

print("lyst is None; returning None")
return None
```